# Disc of convergence

Tags: convergence-divergence, complex-numbers, power-series, laurent-series

I just worked out the disc of convergence of $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(3-i)^n}{n^2}(z+2)^n$$ using the ratio test and I just wanted to check if other people would get the same result.

I got it is convergent in $|z+2|<\frac{3}{10}+\frac{i}{10}$ is this what other people get?

(z is a complex number $i=\sqrt{-1}$)

Comment: How can a positive number be less than a complex non real number?

Comment: I originally had it in the form $|(3-i)(z+2)|<1$ would it be better to leave it like this?

Comment: @Jackie: it is better to write it in the other form, provided you fix the RHS.

Comment: Just realised I forgot to take the modulus so would that be $|z+2|<\frac{1}{10}$?

Comment: @YvesDaoust: The inequality in the question is simply wrong. You cannot have an inequality with a "raw" complex number. So the word "better" is not a good choice because this implies that the inequality in the question is right but not good for this purpose.

Comment: @MrYouMath: the OP perfectly understood what I meant and fixed ! And the qualifier *better* echoes the question in his first comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By Cauchy-Hadamard:

$$\frac1R=\limsup_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{\frac{|3-i|^n}{n^2}}=|3-i|=\sqrt{10}$$